# UI lags for a few seconds when building a large list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, user-experience

When navigating to a page with a large list of UI elements, the UI freezes for a couple of seconds before showing the list. I am guessing this is because the browser tries to repaint the entire DOM with the list of UI elements which takes a some time which in turn freezes the UI for some time.

I have constructed this [webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kjg4xVVIl5_8N38cKZe) which demonstrates this situation. Clicking on the `list` link takes you to the list page which contains a large number of simple square divs. The UI freezes for a few seconds before finally showing the list.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You need to click on the `list` link to go to the list page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, inserting 177147 items at once will indeed lag the UI. What you want to do is *lazily* load the list, so as you scroll down, items are inserted.

Here are two libraries that will help you:

https://github.com/onefinestay/react-lazy-render

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Is the list component a pure component (stateless)? You could try the more efficient route using this method:
[45% Faster React](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f)

Basically instead of rendering your component like this:

```
<Component/>
```

You would render it like this:

```
{Component()}
```

Of course, this is if you do not want to use a handy library.